# AngularJs app breaks when adding to module

Tags: javascript, angularjs

*I have an **angular.js** app that works fine like this...*

```
'use strict';
var urlRouterProvider, stateProvider;


angular.module('myApp', [
    'ngCookies',
    'ngResource',
    'ngSanitize',
    'ui.router',
    'ui.bootstrap',
    'kinvey'  
])
```

*When I try to add a directive **(shown below)***

```
'use strict';
var urlRouterProvider, stateProvider;

angular.module('myApp', [
    'ngCookies',
    'ngResource',
    'ngSanitize',
    'ui.router',
    'ui.bootstrap',
    'kinvey',
    'myApp.directives'   
])
```

*However, it no longer works with the Chrome console saying...*

`"uncaught object"
throw $injectorMinErr('modulerr', "Failed to instantiate module {0} due to:\n{1}",`

Comment: Is the module `myApp.directives` defined before the `myApp` one?

Comment: i think directive name could not be added here, this is for module name injection

Comment: myApp.directives is currently just a file called directive.js with angular.module('myApp.directives', []).directive("rating", function() {
  // code here
});

Comment: Do you have a module named `myApp.directives` and is it included before `myApp`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgot to add it to my index.html sourcefiles